# Show that $\int ^{\infty} _0 \frac{\sin(\omega x)}{x}\,dx$ exists and find its value

Tags: real-analysis, improper-integrals

Show that$$\int^\infty_0 \frac{\sin(\omega x)}{x} \, dx$$ converges for $\omega>0$. What values can the integral have?

---

My approach was

$$\int^\infty_0 \frac{\sin(\omega x)}{x}\,dx=\sum^\infty_{n=0}\left( \int^{(2n+1)\pi/\omega}_{2\pi n/\omega} \frac{\sin(\omega x)}{x} \, dx + \int^{2(n+1)\pi/\omega}_{(2n+1)\pi/\omega} \frac{\sin(\omega x)}{x} \, dx \right)$$

to split up the intervals into the intervals when the function is positive and the intervals when the function is negative.. but since I tried for several hours and since Im stuck I really given up on thinking this is the correct way..

I'm in my first year and my second real Analysis course.. I really dont know how to get further with this task :D especially even when my way is correct to show it converges, it would help me "finding values". My initial idea was sandwiching the Integral, but in that case I first of all would need to know the value beforehand and secondly I couldnt finde any good minors or majors..

maybe someone got an idea how to help me :/

Comment: By making the change of variables $t=\omega x$, the integral reduces to $\int_0^{\infty}\frac{\sin t}{t}\,dt$.This is a very famous integral. Its value is $\frac{\pi}{2}$, and can be proven by complex analysis or by Fubini's theorem or Fourier analysis methods, or by several other methods. If you just want to show the integral exits, you can integrate by parts on $\int_1^{\infty}$.

Comment: If you want to know the value before trying to prove anything, you can [ask WolframAlpha](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=integrate+sin%28omega*x%29%2Fx+dx+from+0+to+infinity) and then you know that the answer seems to be $\pi/2$ even if you don't know why yet.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your method is usually used to prove that the integrale is not Absolutely convergent.

With the change $ t=\omega x$, it becomes
$$\int_0^\infty \frac{\sin(t)}{t}dt$$

near $ 0^+ $, it converges since
$$\lim_{t\to0^+}\frac{\sin(t)}{t}=1$$

near infinity, by parts

$$\Bigl[\frac{-\cos(t)}{t}\Bigr]_1^X-\int_1^X\frac{\cos(t)}{t^2}dt$$

has a limit when $ X\to \infty$.

Comment: ahh okey wow.. yeah that solves the part with the convergence.. any way to also get values? :)

Comment: To get its value, you consider the function $ F(x)=\int_0^\infty \frac{\sin(t)}{t}e^{-xt}dt$ for $ x>0$ and prove that $ F $ satisfies some differential equation.